# Editable tree view inside a form view is not saving

Tags: forms, tree, many-to-many, odoo, odoo-11

I have an editable tree view inside my form view.

See this picture:

[image]

I can edit the values inside the tree, but every time I hit the Save button at the top, it doesn't save the updated values inside my tree. It goes back to default (in this case 0).
Below is the code for my form view:

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="score_card_form_view">
    <field name="name">Score Card</field>
    <field name="model">golf_online_ph.score_card</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <sheet>
                <group string="Score Card">
                    <field name="round_id" />
                    <field name="player_id" />
                    <field name="round_holes">
                        <tree editable="top" >
                            <field name="hole_number" readonly="1"/>
                            <field name="score_value"/>
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                </group>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

What should be my workaround here?

Comment: Add the code with models definitions and any extra details

Answer (score 1):

Hello @Adrian Steven Quevada,
Your solved? Else update more info about fields. Because your view seems right.